# Cannot call localhost deployed on laptop from Android device

Tags: c#, android, iis, asp.net-web-api

Here is my situation:

1. On my laptop (running Windows 8.1), I have deployed a Web API (written in C#) to my
   localhost. I can access this service from laptop browser. The
   address is http://localhost:8089/api/... blah blah
2. My laptop and my Android device are connecting to the same WiFi network, because I'm testing this at home.
3. I added an Inbound Rule on Firewall for port 8089.
4. My laptop IP is: 192.168.0.8, but when I call http://192.168.0.8:8089/api/... from my Android device, it said `Connection refused`.

What should I do now to make my service available to my device? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like a firewall thing, have you tried some regular port? Like to expose your apis directly from port `80`?

Comment: Have you tried same ip address in your pc ? In pc browser is it working ?

Comment: @CliveDM: I'll try, but I already added Inbound Rule for port 8089.

Comment: @shreyashmashru: in my laptop, I just call http://localhost:8089/api/... and it's working normally.

Comment: @shreyashmashru: I added binding to my website in IIS, so now I can call http://192.168.0.8:8089/api/... from my browser normally. But the connection made from Android device is still refused.

Comment: @Forte_201092: One more try can you check from your mobile browser that is it working ?

Comment: @shreyashmashru: no, it doesn't :(

Comment: @Forte_201092: Please try port 80 or without giving port, If it does not help then please post your binding or provide demo so i can check it.